# DQL with conditions in SUM

Tags: mysql, doctrine, dql

I have a DQL like this:

```
$dql = "SELECT d.name, "
. "SUM(m.id and m.status = 'a') members, "
. "SUM(m.position_id = 19 and m.status = 'a') subcon, "
. "SUM(m.position_id = 20 and m.status = 'a') ojt, "
. "SUM(m.status = 'h') hr_intra "
. "FROM OssOrgBundle:User m "
. "RIGHT JOIN OssOrgBundle:Department d "
. "ON m.department = d.id "
. "GROUP BY d.id";

$qb = $em->createQuery($dql);
deptListCount = $qb->getResult();
```

does doctrine support aggregate function SUM with a condition inside it?
I tried the query in SQL, and it works.
I am having trouble converting it to DQL

I also did this using:

```
$deptListCount = $em->createQueryBuilder("r")
->select("d.name")
->addSelect("SUM(m.id AND m.status = 'a') members")
->addSelect("SUM(m.position_id = 19 and m.status = 'a') subcon")
->addSelect("SUM(m.position_id = 20 and m.status = 'a') ojt")
->addSelect("SUM(m.status = 'h') hr_intra ")
->from("OssOrgBundle:Department", "d")
->leftJoin("OssOrgBundle:User", "m", "WITH", "m.deprtment = :id")
->groupBy("d.id")
->getQuery()
->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

still not working

Answer (score 3):

No in doctrine you need to use `case when` for conditional `sum`

```
sum( case when m.position_id = 19 and m.status = 'a' then 1 else 0 end ) as subcon
```

Change for the rest in DQL and also

`m.id AND m.status = 'a'` not sure what logic you are trying to apply I assume you are looking for something as

```
sum( case when m.id is not null and m.status = 'a' then 1 else 0 end ) as members
```